# Protect content wih XX?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, flash

I have a webpage (ruby on rails) with some text that I would like to protect the content in order to block the user to copy it (ctrl+c).

Of course that I have some "protection" but it's not enough

```
$(function(){
    $('a.fancybox').fancybox();
    $('.prevent_select').disableSelection();
});


$.support.selectstart = "onselectstart" in document.createElement("div");
$.fn.disableSelection = function() {
    return this.bind( ( $.support.selectstart ? "selectstart" : "mousedown" ) +
        ".ui-disableSelection", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
};
```

If the user uses CTRL+A all the text is selected. I have in my mind two ways in order to protect it. But I would like to share with you in order to have some feedback.

- Is it possible to use an swf (Macromedia flash) in order to show the text? (some GEM?)
- Is it possible to "delete" always the user buffer when the webpage detects that the user is using ctrl+c?
- Do you have other ideas?

I really appreciate your feedback and help.

Comment: It's not worth to try. 

On the one hand if you use flash or images instead of pure html, users with disabilities or Google will not able to read it. This will be bad for you. On the other hand trying to prevent copy'n'paste with javascript or transparent images is useless. The content is already on the user's computer, he can extract it by looking into the source code or by disabling javascript. It is just annoying for normal users, whereas people who want to steel your context can to it anyway.

Comment: This is not possible. If you want the user to be able to read the text, then he needs to be able to see it. I.e. display it on the screen. If it is displayed on the screen, there are all sorts of ways to grab it: read the screen buffer, make a photo of the screen, heck, take pen and paper and write it down. You cannot prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw text using a canvas. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ExWei/hZmM2/

You can place transparent image on text zone. (using a CSS)

Script for blocking <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  - <kbd>A</kbd>:

```
document.ondragstart = test;
document.onselectstart = test;
document.oncontextmenu = test;
function test() 
{
    return false;
}

document.oncontextmenu;

function catchControlKeys(event)
{
    var code=event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : null;
    if (event.ctrlKey)
    {
        // Ctrl+U
        if (code == 117) return false;
        if (code == 85) return false;
        // Ctrl+C
        if (code == 99) return false;
        if (code == 67) return false;
        // Ctrl+A
        if (code == 97) return false;
        if (code == 65) return false;
    }
}
```

For using this script change

```
<body>
```

to

```
<body onkeypress="return catchControlKeys(event)">
```